# Microsoft.Graph api set user Extension Property

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

We've used the Microsoft Graph API for a while to set the value of an extended property. Previously we've used the Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient, but since a year there a a Microsoft.Graph Nuget package. With the Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient there was a method called SetExtendedProperty, but there is no such thing in the Microsoft.Graph package. Does anyone have a suggestion how to set the Extension Property with the Microsoft.Graph package?

If you need some more info please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

You could create the schema extensions with microsoft graph sdk v1.4.0 version . Related discussion&code sample [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/132) and [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/151) are for your reference .

For example ,to create a schema extension for groups :

```
// Create a schema extension for groups.
SchemaExtension extensionDefinition = new SchemaExtension()
{
    Description = "This extension correlates a group with a foreign database.",
    Id = $"crmForeignKey", // Microsoft Graph will prepend 8 chars
    Properties = new List<ExtensionSchemaProperty>()
    {
        new ExtensionSchemaProperty() { Name = "fid", Type = "Integer" }
    },
    TargetTypes = new List<string>()
    {
        "Group"
    }
};

// Create the schema extension. This results in a call to Microsoft Graph.
SchemaExtension schemaExtension = await graphClient.SchemaExtensions.Request().AddAsync(extensionDefinition);
```

Then create a  class for the extension:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyDBExtensionClass
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "fid", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default)]
    public int FID { get; set; }

    public MyDBExtensionClass(int fid)
    {
        FID = fid;
    }
}
```

Next , set the schema extension properties to a existed group by update `AdditionalData` property of group:

```
        // Update a group.
        // This snippet changes the group name. 
        // This snippet requires an admin work account. 
        public async Task<List<ResultsItem>> UpdateGroup(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string id, string name)
        {
            List<ResultsItem> items = new List<ResultsItem>();
            IDictionary<string, object> extensionInstance = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            extensionInstance.Add(extensionIDYouGet, new MyDBExtensionClass(1213));
            // Update the group.
            await graphClient.Groups[id].Request().UpdateAsync(new Group
            {
                DisplayName = Resource.Updated + name,
                AdditionalData= extensionInstance
            });

            items.Add(new ResultsItem
            {

                // This operation doesn't return anything.
                Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { Resource.No_Return_Data, "" }
                }
            });
            return items;
        }
```

You could also add the extension to a new create group as shown as above link .

Update :

Your requirement is setting the schema extension properties to user , then update `AdditionalData` property of user :

```
  await graphClient.Users["ID"].Request().UpdateAsync(new User
            {
                DisplayName = Resource.Updated + name,
                AdditionalData = extensionInstance

            });
```

And if you want to create schema extension for user entity , `User`value should includes in `TargetTypes` property of SchemaExtension object.