# Schema Extension Value is always NULL when updating through Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-api

Step 1:

Created GraphServiceClient using Microsoft.Graph 4.9.0 and Microsoft.Graph.Core 2.0.5 SDK

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, new ClientSecretCredentialOptions()
{
     AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
});`


GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
```

Step 2:

And created a custom schema extension like below.

```
SchemaExtension schemaExtension = new SchemaExtension()
{
     Id = "data1",
     Description = "creating test schema extn",
     TargetTypes = new List<string>()
     {
         "User"
     },
     Properties = new List<ExtensionSchemaProperty>()
     {
         new ExtensionSchemaProperty()
         {
              Name ="prop1",
              Type ="String"
         }
     }
};
```

Step 3:

Updated the Schema extension status to "Available"

```
var updatedExtn = await graphServiceClient
             .SchemaExtensions[schemaExtension.Id].Request()
             .UpdateAsync(new SchemaExtension()
             {
                 Status = "Available"
             });
```

Step 4:

Create Class for extension data

```
public class data1
{
    // You must serialize your property names to camelCase if your SchemaExtension describes as such.
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "prop1", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default)]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

Step 5:

Find the User and add the created schema extension to the user

```
IDictionary<string, object> extensionInstance = new Dictionary<string, object>();
// The below line is not working. but doesn't throw error
extensionInstance.Add(schemaExtension.Id, new data1 { prop1 = "testing" });

var usrCollection = await graphServiceClient.Users
           .Request()
           .Filter($"userPrincipalNames  eq '{adelev_Mail}'")
           .GetAsync();
 
var usr = usrCollection.FirstOrDefault();

if(usr != null)
{
     usr.AdditionalData.Add(extensionInstance);

     var updatedUser = await graphServiceClient.Users[usr.Id]
               .Request()
               .UpdateAsync(usr);
}
```

Step 6:

When you try to retrieve the extension the value is NULL.

```
User updatedUser = await graphServiceClient.Users[usr.Id].Request()
                .Select($"id, {schemaExtension.Id}")
                .GetAsync();
```

But it works with API using Graph Explorer.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}
{
    "extXXXXXXXX_data1":
     {
          "prop1" : "testing"
     }
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing anything here. Any help here is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should accessing the data on `AdditionalData` property. Try looking at `user.AdditionalData` in your result. Here is a screenshot with my example.

Getting User with Schema extension from Graph explorer.
[image]

While using the SDK, i access my custom data in `user.AdditionalData`

[image]

Check [this thread - Graph SDK and SchemaExtensions](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/238) for details.

Comment: I'm having trouble with Step 5 in the question. I'm trying to add the extension data via SDK and I could be able to add them but the values are always null. 

Could you please help me figuring out why the schema extension values are null when adding through SDK?

Comment: Are you able to see the data you add in level 5 through Graph explorer? You can check [this thread on how to add extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676448/microsoft-graph-api-set-user-extension-property) and let me know.

Comment: yes, i can able to view the data from Step 5. Only the prob I'm facing is adding the extension values (data) programmatically.